# Psycopg2 None type column

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

```
for table in tables:

speedy_serve_cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM "%s"' % table[0])
for row in speedy_serve_cursor.fetchall():
    if len(row) == 1:
        row = row[0]
        print (table[0])
        print (row)
        archives_cursor.execute('INSERT INTO "%s" VALUES (%s) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING' % (table[0], str(row)))

    else:
        print (table[0])
        print("\n\n")
        print (row)
        print("\n\n\n\n")
        archives_cursor.execute('INSERT INTO "%s" VALUES (%s) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING' % (table[0], str(row)[1:-1]))
```

I'm using the following code to copy over a table from one Postgresql database to another. However, I'm getting an error "Column none does not exist". I tried using parameters in my query statements but no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: Probably duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41965879/python-postgres-best-way-to-insert-data-from-table-on-one-db-to-another-table-on/41966305#41966305

Comment: what's output of the `print`s you have there?

Comment: print(table[0]) correctly gives me the name of the table and print(row) also correctly gives each row in the table